# Update To Query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a working code and a working query which is as follows.

```
$temp = $this->db->select('name as label, name as value')->like('name', $term, 'ALL')->get('states')->result_array();
```

I want this query to work on the mentioned table and bring all the results that have even a single match. I want to use LIKE %$term% thing in the query. I tried this.

```
$temp = $this->db->select('name as label, name as value')->like('name', '%'.$term.'%', 'ALL')->get('states')->result_array();
```

But it did not work. In fact when I checked the query there was something strange happening. I entered 4680 in the search box where as in the query it was appearing like F8%..

Can any one help that how can I update this query?

Waiting for your response.
Thanks

Comment: you need "both" as third parameter in ->like(,,'both')...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$temp = $this->db->select('name as label, name as value', false)->like('name', $term, 'BOTH')->get('states')->result_array();
```